# Chrome window.location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to redirect a page when click on a button. My JavaScript code works fine in Mozilla Firefox but in Chrome. There is a problem.

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
    if ($('#email').val() == "user") {
        if ($('#password').val() == "pass") {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com.tr";
        } else {
            alert("Invalid Password");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Invalid UserID");
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Try `window.location.href`

Comment: Tried just window.location = "..." in Chrome console and it worked just fine.

Comment: Problem is, my code doesn't redirect to google page when i click the button. I tried window.location.href but it doesn't work.

Comment: What button? Show us a complete test case. What does the JS console say?

Comment: I hope you're not *really* putting the email address and password in plain view inside your Javascript.

Comment: @Flas it did not work.

Comment: JS console does't give any error or alert, it works fine in Mozilla Firefox but in Chrome doesn't.

Comment: can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Ok, try to replace window.location with console.log('test') to see if your condition exectues at all.

Comment: Yes it works. It is already working in Mozilla but there is a problem in Chrome i think.,

Comment: @rockStar,  <input type="submit" id="login" value="Log In" onclick="myFunction()" />

Comment: As previously requested - please provide a *complete* (reduced) test case. The minimal code needed to reproduce the problem (having a live demon on jsbin.com would be nice too).

Answer (score -1):

`window.location.href = <specific url>` should work (worked for me in chrome).

Alternative to it with more options is [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

```
function myFunction()
{
  if ($('#email').val() == "user") {
    if ($('#password').val() == "pass") {
      window.open('http://www.google.com.tr', '_self');
    } else {
      alert("Invalid Password");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Invalid UserID");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

the proper way of doing a `window.location` is:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com.tr';
```

this should work now.

Comment: "Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also assign a DOMString to it. This means that you can work with window.location as if it were a string in most cases: window.location = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'." — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: yup, but the thing is,chrome usually identifies it as just a string passed into the object, it is better to use the `href` property. I forgot where i read that but i think it was like that

Comment: Chrome supports having a string assigned to it just fine.